# using PowerShell ImportExcel module how do i get <mergeCells count="xxx">

Tags: powershell

is there a way in the PowerShell ImportExcel module to get the mergeCells count value?
, i haven't written any code yet as not sure if the value is available via the module, and if so loop through a folder and check all xlsx files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We're here to help as soon as you can show us what code you've written so far, so once you've written some code include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!